# Catch the change in image using seleniumIDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Is it possible to identify the change in image using `selenium IDE`?
There is two images,one will appear for active mode and another one will be for inactive mode,can i verify that image-change according to the functionality that i specified above[Active/Inactive].
Please help me.
Associated HTML:

Comment: please specify what actualy your need is?

Comment: Could you show the assoaciated html ?

Comment: Associated HTML: <img src="http://10.10.10.32/Assets/Images/OFF.png" class="imgSwtich" title="OFF">

Answer (score 2):

If you have an attribute for ON/OFF mode, you can use a lot of assert* commands and find img tag by xPath.

For example, add in Seleinum IDE row with

assertElementPresent //img[@title="OFF"]

or

assertElementPresent //img[@title="ON"]